# How can I set Android Studio to display correct international string when it builds an App?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know the error information will be displayed when I build an Android Studio app.

But sometimes that Android Studio display messy code for build result just like Image A.

How can I set Android Studio to display correct international string when it builds an App?

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: What is your system? Windows? Mac?

Comment: It's Microsoft Windows

Comment: That looks like an encoding issue but it could just be unprintable binary data. Do you know what is supposed to be displayed where those diamonds are? The actual encoding and character codes?

Comment: How can I set  encoding for build information in Android Studio?